# can't login google cloud vm instance after reset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serial-port, google-compute-engine

I reset the instance after some codes hung up the server.
and then I was not able to login with the ssh tool

[image]

In the serial port log, I found this:
.......................

```
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for /etc/rc....atibility (12hours 57s / no limit)
```

I have one serial port console now. but which commands should I use? 
Please help me.

[image]

Port 22 is listening but I have not set any passwords or ssh keys. So I only can login by the google ssh web tool

Comment: I have solved this by mounted the disk to another instance, it was caused by a file under /etc whose name is group.*.lock, just removed it and it's up again

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused if you put long-running commands in rc.local so it is expected that the server will take some time to boot. See the Stack Exchange question in [1]

I would give the VM some time (minutes) and let it finish the processes.

If the issue persists you should contact Google Cloud Support to assist you with your VM instance. See link [2] for information on how to contact support.

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/616757/a-start-job-is-running-for-etc-rc-local-compatibility-how-to-fix

[2] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?

Comment: thanks for reply. The google support suggest me that create a new instance and mount the old disk to it and check what happened on it :(